# Determining functions from specifications...

Tags: calculus

my high school teacher asked this question today, and I am struggling to find an answer that will work. The question is outlined below:

Give an example of a cubic polynomial, defined on the open interval (-3,3), which reaches both its maximum and minimum values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f(x) = x^3 - 3c^2 x
$$
for some $c$. At $\pm 3$, the values are $\mp 3(3^2- c^2) = \mp 3(9-c^2)$; the derivative is $3x^2 - 3c^2$, which is zero at $x = \pm c$; the function value at those points is $\pm(c^3 - 3c^3) = \mp 2c^3$.

You want the value at the "bumps" to be the max, so you need to pick $c$ so that, for instance, $2c^3 > 3(9-c^2)$, or 
$$
2c^3 + 3c^2 - 27 > 0
$$

Randomly checking, I find that $c = 2$ seems to work.

The key idea is that a cubic either has "no humps" or "two humps" or the special "one inflextion where the derivative is zero (like $y = x^3$). The two-hump case is the only hope for this problem, where the max occurs either at critical points or at the ends of the interval. The archetypal 2-hump cubic is $y = x^3 - x$; I threw in a constant just to adjust the width/height of the humps, and the $3$ was to simplify the algebra a bit (as was using $c^2$ instead of $c$).

Having done that, I just needed for the y-value, at the critical points, to be higher than the values at $x = \pm 3$ (and I needed the critical points inside the interval $(-3, 3)$. So I fudged around a little to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For instance
$$
P_3(x)=x(x+3)(x-3).
$$
See the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%28x%2B3%29%20%28x-3%29%20x%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your contribution!!!

This cubic is defined on the open interval only. The function described above would work in a closed interval, but as this is the open interval the points 3 and -3 are not in the domain of the function to be determined

Comment: The function that he has given is defined on the open interval as well; if it is defined on the closed interval, then it must be defined on any part that fits within that interval!

Comment: By the way, any polynomial is defined everywhere, since it is a polynomial...