# Give a cubic polynomial, defined on the open interval (-5,4), which reaches both its min and max values

Tags: calculus

Give a cubic polynomial, defined on the open interval (-5,4), which reaches both its min and max values.

I don't know if there is a direct approach to solving this but I have been stuck on it for a while and I don't know what the answer is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you model your variant after http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130232/determining-functions-from-specifications?

Comment: That worked, Thanks.

Comment: I'd try finding a polynomial where f(-5)=0, f(4)=0, f'(-5)=1, f(4)=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cubic polynomial will yield its minimum and maximum values between its most negative root (a) and its most positive root (c) and the remaining root b must be between a and c.

f(x)=(x-a)*(x-b)*(x-c)

In your case, this question has multiple answers and a safe bet would be to place the roots as follows:
a = -5
c = 4
b = anywhere in between a and c (perhaps right in the average of (a+c)/2 for a nice symmetric plot).